# Web Os app development using angular isuue

Tags: television, webos, lg

When the IPK is created and installed on the TV, it doesn’t work. I used the app root tag in HTML to run this in the simulator and live server. When I create a basic app to print “Hello, World” and run it on the TV, it works. Can I get the changes to be made to achieve this on the TV?

I have created an Angular web application and loaded it into WebOS by adding the scripts built by Angular into the index.html file in a basic WebOS setup. I achieved this using a VS Code extension. The live server is working fine. While running it in the simulator by launching it, everything works fine.